# Physical interpretation of Fourier $[x(t)]$ where $x(t)$ is the position of mass $m$ as a function of time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform

If a macroscopic body of mass $m$ moves according to a certain law of motion like, for example, $$x(t)=A\cos(2\pi ft)$$ then what physical interpretation can be attributed to the Fourier transform of $x(t)$?

Comment: Just a check re your comments. Do you mean the Fourier *transform* or the Fourier *series*? They require different methods to tackle and I interpret them in different ways. A Fourier Transform is like $\mathcal{F}[1]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i \omega x} dx=2\pi\delta(\omega)$. A Fourier series is like $f(x)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty A_n e^{i \omega n x}$.

Comment: "Do you mean the Fourier transform or the Fourier series?" I mean the Fourier transform because $x(t)$ can be any function, not necessarily a periodical one.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you what is the spectral content of the motion.

Some examples of when this might be interesting:

- The object being measured is a point on a guitar string---then it would tell you what note  is being played
- The object being measured is a planet. Then the peak frequency of the motion is the inverse of the planet's year.
- The object being measured is part of a mechanical actuator---then the spectral response due to an applied force impulse (or driving signal) could tell you about the requirements for a control system for that actuator to remain stable. Generally in a linear system if you can measure the spectrum of the response to a know input with known frequency content then you can predict the response to other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the Fourier transform will be a dirac pointing the unique frequency of vibration $f$  (or indeed 2, at $-f$ and $f$), with amplitude $A$ and phase $0$.

Comment: I am interested in finding a physical interpretation of $F[x(t)]$. I know how the [Fourier transform of a cosine function](http://www.etcs.ipfw.edu/~lin/ECET357/2007Spring/Lectures/7_FourierTransforms_S07_1_3_S07.html) looks like.

Comment: what do you expect so different to the notion of spectrum ? one space have the vibrating motions. The other is the set of "vibrations numbers". You directly see modes in that space, isn't it something big enough ?

Comment: BTW your example is a bit borring (too simple). the membrane of a loudspeaker, or vibrating exchangers pipes would be more rich.